# EXC_BREAKPOINT crash. Possible Jailbreak issue?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, crash, jailbreak

I received a crash report from Crashlytics today and can't figure out what the problem is. My app has been live for months without issue, so this appears to be a one off.

The crash is `Exception Type EXC_BREAKPOINT Code UNKNOWN at 0xdefe`

```
1    UIKit   _shadowImageInRectForSlice + 258
2    UIKit   _shadowImageInRectForSlice + 258
3    UIKit   -[UIActionSheet(Private) layout] + 3586
4    UIKit   -[UIActionSheet(Private) presentSheetInView:] + 268
5    myapp   GraphViewController.m line 135
             -[GraphViewController graphButtonPressed:] + 135
6    UIKit   -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 72
7    UIKit   -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 120
8    UIKit   -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 72
9    UIKit  -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 30
10   UIKit  -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44
11   UIKit  -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 502
12   UIKit  -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 488
13   UIKit  -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 524
14   UIKit  -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 380
15   UIKit  _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6154
16   GraphicsServices   _PurpleEventCallback + 590
17   GraphicsServices   PurpleEventCallback + 34
18   CoreFoundation     __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
19   CoreFoundation     __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 138
20   CoreFoundation     __CFRunLoopRun + 1384
21   CoreFoundation     CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
22   CoreFoundation     CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
23   GraphicsServices   GSEventRunModal + 74
24   UIKit  UIApplicationMain + 1120
25   myapp   main.m line 16
             main + 16
```

Now line 135 of the ViewController it simply `[actionSheet showInView:self.view];` for a `UIActionSheet`

The crash occurred on an iPad2.5 (Not sure which model that is) but my app is iPhone only, so would have been windowed. And iOS 6.1

The other thing to note, is the device was Jailbroken. Could this have caused the crash? I know they could have installed any kind of plugin to manipulate views.

----------ADDITIONAL----------

Whilst writing this, I received a 2nd crash report and it appears to be from a different user as this time it's iOS 5.1.1 on an iPhone4.1. This phone was also jailbroken.

`Exception Type EXC_BAD_ACCESS Code KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x4003109b`

```
0    libobjc.A.dylib     objc_msgSend + 15
1    UIKit   -[UIActionSheet(Private) _buttonClicked:] + 250
2    CoreFoundation  -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 52
3    UIKit   -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 62
4    UIKit   -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 30
5    UIKit   -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44
6    UIKit   -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 492
7    UIKit   -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 476
8    UIKit   -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 318
9    UIKit   -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 380
10   UIKit   -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 356
11   UIKit   _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5826
12   GraphicsServices    PurpleEventCallback + 882
13   CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 38
14   CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 140
15   CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 1370
16   CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
17   CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
18   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal + 136
19   UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 1080
20   myapp  main.m line 16
            main + 16
```

This one doesn't even show which `ViewController` caused the crash!

Any ideas please?

Comment: Have you ever solved this problem?

Comment: No, I've put it down to Jailbreak mods. You having the same issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please note that this kind of stuff is very hard to debug, especially without the code and any other context than this crashlogs. I'll try to give some directions/thing I would do.

First of [iPad 2,5 seems to be the iPad mini WiFi](http://www.imore.com/regarding-ipad-25-and-ipad-26), but I'm not entirely sure about this. So test your App on an iPad mini (also test on an device with iOS 5.1.1) and see what happens, focus on `UIActionSheet` instances you use and start testing in the `GraphViewController`. Make sure all cases you can think of work correctly.

If that works and these are the only 2 crashreports you've got: **Don't panic!** I don't know how many users your App has, but only 2 of them had this crash once. You say they probably jailbroken their devices, they know Apps can crash because of that.

With that in mind decide if it's worth the time and effort to put more time into solving this problem.

If it is you could look at objects or blocks that could be released during the use of a `UIActionSheet` instance, `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` basically says 'OMG, the object we must use is gone!'.

`EXC_BREAKPOINT` most of the times tells you that you're referencing a symbol or framework which doesn't exist. That could be because the phone is jailbroken or because you say you're App is compatible with iOS version X but you're using frameworks/methods that are only available in more recent version. So check for that also.

I hope this way you find some suspicious code and be able to post that here on StackOverflow or you can solve the issue yourself.

Hope this gives a little help in the right direction, but, once again, only a crashreport without the code or the ability to do some testing is not much to go on...

Comment: "you're referencing a symbol or framework which doesn't exist. That could be because the phone is jailbroken" - Absolutely not.

Comment: If the jailbroken device has a mod installed that skins the `UIActionSheet` or replaces it with a "improved" version of the `UIActionSheet` such thing is possible. It is more likely that the developer did something that isn't supported on the relevant iOS version, but I've seen crazy crashes from jailbroken devices with unstable mods installed. (Of course just the jailbreak itself is of little to no harm.)